# Typescript + React call parent method from child component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to call parent method from child component, but it doesn't work and method in parent element is not triggered. In this example I have only two components where `ChildHello` calls method in `Hello` component.

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/7wqx6q6w1j)

**Hello.tsx**

```
import * as React from "react";

interface Props {
  itemClicked: () => void;
}

export class Hello extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
  }

  itemClicked = val => {
    console.log(val);
  };

  render() {
    const { name } = this.props;
    return <h1 itemClicked={this.itemClicked}>{this.props.children}</h1>;
  }
}

const styles = {
  height: "400px"
};

export class ChildHello extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.props.itemClicked} style={styles}>
        <Hello>Hello Child</Hello>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: scope in parent use `this.itemClicked.bind(this)`

Comment: @Lostfields it didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand parent child relationship
in childHello you are using the click event.

```
 <div onClick={this.props.itemClicked} style={styles}>
        <Hello>Hello Child</Hello>
      </div>
```

childhello is called by the index.jsx page

```
 <div style={styles}>
    <ChildHello name="CodeSandbox" />
  </div>
```

Here you are not passing any click events. also, hello component is inside the child component which is wrong.

All the parent component should have click method involved and that method should be passed as props.

Like this

Parent:

```
<div style={styles}>
    <Hello name="CodeSandbox" />
  </div>
```

Hello component

```
render() {
    const { name } = this.props;
    return <ChildHello itemClicked={this.itemClicked} />;
  }
```

ChildHello

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.props.itemClicked} style={styles}>
        Hello
      </div>
    );
  }
```

[Sandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/o9xo182oz)